# call exporter with python

Tags: python, export

I see that it's possible to call a basic exporter, like fbx, with a command like:

```
bpy.ops.export_scene.fbx(...)
```

But, what if I want to use any of the other exporting format like STL, PLY, or Babylon? Is there a way call these other exporters? Or any other exporters that could be defined in an addon?

A way to call any exporters by just specifying the name of the addon.

Thanks

Comment: You can call any export operator, but you should ensure it exists and perhaps enable the required export addon so that it does. Go to Python console, type `bpy.ops.export` and hit *Spacebar* for auto-complete and check out all the available operators. Auto-complete will also reveal the operator signature (all available options you can use). Check the operator log after an export via UI to see the arguments used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found a way to track all operations by typing

```
bpy.app.debug_wm = True
```

in the script window.

From this, you see too much information, but you can see the actually operations.

To export with

- Babylon.js: bpy.ops.scene.babylon(filepath="test.babylon")
- STL: bpy.ops.export_mesh.stl(filepath="untitled.stl")

Hope this will help other people.